how to create google cast receiver without device
How to deploy Google CastReceiver on our own device without a Google Cast device, and then use the Android MediaRouteButton function to search for and connect to the CastReceiver
Integrate Google cast receiver functionality on your own hardware device

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
